# How to handle errors correctly in django?

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-views

I have a question, I know that it is possible to do global exception handling in python, but how to do it for all views, namely, I am interested in DetailView, but others will also come in handy.I understand that you need to give your own examples of solutions, but could you give an example of how this can be done, because I have no ideas at all how to do it.
I want to do global error handling so that it can be done like this

```
 try:
      current_profile = Profile.objects.get(user_connected_id=current_user_object)
 except ObjectDoesNotExist SomeERROR....:
     logger.info('Object user_connected_id not found....')
     raise ObjectDoesNotExist
```

And if I don't handle the error that appears, then I want it to work in the global handler. And if it's not difficult: what should I do correctly with errors in this handler, other than logging?
I need the DetailView handler most of all

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The methodology here involves a couple things. First, within those views, you want to make sure you are getting those errors within an `except` block as your code does. Then you should return an `HttpResponseRedirect` object redirecting  the user to the error page or another page where you would like for the user to return.

The next thing you can do is return a particular view for all errors of a type on the site when they hit `urls.py`. For example, to redirect all 404 errors, add the following code to the base site `urls.py`

```
handler404 = 'App.views.error_404_view'
```

Then, in the view simply return the custom error page you'd like or perform a new `HttpResponseRedirect`

```
def error_404_view(request, exception):
    return render(request, 'error_404.html')
```

Answer (score 2):

First of all you should think on what errors you want to expose. Usually 4xx errors (Errors that are attributed to the client-side) are disclosed so the user may correct the request. On the other side, 5xx errors (Errors that are attributed to the server-side) are usually only presented without information.

try something like that -

```
    try:
        test_method(form.cleaned_data)
    except `PermissionError` as e:
        status_code= 403
```